# How can I save user preferences for my iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, settings

I am building one Application and need to enter the access credentials (Org code, accesscode) before opening the application. when the user enter the access permissions for the first time then we need to save the preferences. When the user open the app again, automatically he need to continue with application but not with access credentials.

[And I build the code here](http://pastie.org/7761163)

There are no errors in log cat but preferences are not saving. I need to save the preferences and load when the application opens by the user. Am I doing anything wrong in the code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This common function is to add your data to NSUserDefaults.. Look this is Class functions so You have to call this using your class name.. Write this in your AppDelegate implementation file..

```
+(void)addToNSUserDefaults:(id)pObject forKey:(NSString*)pForKey
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:pObject forKey:pForKey];
    [defaults synchronize]; 
}
```

This is to get data from NSUserDefaults..

```
+(id)getFromNSUserDefaults:(NSString*)pForKey
{
    id pReturnObject;
    NSUserDefaults *defaults =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    pReturnObject = [defaults valueForKey:pForKey];
    return pReturnObject;
}
```

When you start application, Just Check this in this method of AppDelegate,

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions 
{
    NSString *strtmp = [AppDelegate getFromNSUserDefaults:YOUR_KEY];

    if(strtmp == nil)
    {
        //User have to enter data to save in User Defaults
    }
    else
    {
        //Application Starts without entering Code, as you have it in your UserDefaults
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mehul, I had updated with the code...but the preferences are not saving. I will send you the source code.Can you check it once..

Comment: attaching the code by here is complex.I will send you the code through gmail. Can I have your mail id please.. I need to solve the issue and submit to iTunes by today(urgent requirement)..

Comment: thank you very much.. Can I send you the total code Or implementation files is enough.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29401/discussion-between-mehul-and-kumarsu)

Comment: @Mehul can you help me in this props?